# Getting error from dspam on fedora

Tags: fedora, dspam

I have two servers , Fedora 14 with dspam 3.9.0.19 , Fedora 15 with dspam 3.9.0.21
The old dspam is working fine, while the new one is giving me this error:

dspam[23110]: segfault at 7f5baafe9dc0 ip 00007f5baa32415b sp 00007f5baa31a140 error 4 in libhash_drv.so.7.0.0[7f5baa320000+6000]

dspam.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11

I tried to downgrade the dspam version on Fedora 15 but with no luck 
and the process die in about 10 minutes.

**Update** : Seems there was a bug with dspam 3.9.0 I have updated it to 3.10 and it worked fine

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you're not familiar with C, all you can do is run `dspam` via `strace`:

```
$ strace -o /tmp/dspam.strace dspam
```

or `gdb`:

```
$ gdb dspam
(gdb) run
(gdb) bt full
```

and submit this info to `dspam` developers.